# Drupal popup window returning of value

Tags: javascript, drupal

I want a popup window where the user can choose between 2 options. When the user chooses option 1, form['loading_type'] must have value of "Loading Type A", otherwise it gets a value of "Loading Type B". 
I am using Drupal 6 as my CMS, PHP for the form, and Javascript for my popup.

It might help, but below are snippets of my code:

```
$form['loading_type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
);
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'accountability-button-confirm'),
);

$(document).ready(
function(){
  $('.accountability-button-confirm').click(
    function(){
      return Drupal.popups.open(
        Drupal.t('Loading Type:'),
        Drupal.t("Please choose loading type."),
          {
           'Yes': {
             title: Drupal.t('Loading Type A'),
             func: function(){
              Drupal.popups.close();
              document.getElementById("loading_type").value = "Loading Type A";
              $("form#name-of-my-from-form").submit();
            }
           },
           'No': {
             title: Drupal.t('Loading Type B'),
             func: function(){
              Drupal.popups.close();
              document.getElementById("loading_type").value = "Loading Type B";
              $("form#name-of-my-from-form").submit();
            }
           },
         400
       );
    }
```

Please do help. (I'm a Drupal newbie.) Thanks a lot!